# Убрать\добавить select-элемент в React

Tags: css, reactjs

Дано: `React js` + фреймворк `react-select` (https://react-select.com/).

Надо сделать: По нажатию кнопки компонент  появляется/исчезает.

Обычно такое реализуется примерно так:
В `state` создаётся флажок. В случае стандартного компонента (не из сторонней библиотеки), например кнопки, делаем так:  `<button style={{ visibility: (this.state.myFlag == "1") ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }} >`. Но в библиотеке `react-select` свой `style`, он там [называется styles и устанавливается через опять же свои customStyles](https://react-select.com/styles).

Вопрос: как мне туда встроить смену видимости компонента?

Comment: Просто не надо его рендерить `isVisible && <Component />`

Comment: Не понял ни вообще, ни по частям. `isVisible` это что?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался.
Надо было искать не в пропсах или стилях конкретной библиотеки (хотя так тоже наверное можно, но гораздо сложнее). Ответ универсальный для любого компонента.
В функции render() оборачиваем наш компонент:

```
 {this.state.myFlag == '1' ? <Select bla-bla /> : null }
```

Comment: В официальной документации об этом рассказывается https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator